# Method for returning icon not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a method that takes a string and an integer as parameters. The method basically returns a smaller cropped section of the original image. The string is the path and the integer I am using in a switch statement for the specific sections that I need, I have tried print outs but for whatever reason x and y stay at 0 even though I know that I am getting values for the height and the width.

```
    private  Icon extractIcon(String path, int i){
    // reads the image into a BufferedImage object
    BufferedImage image=null;
    try{
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Image not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    height = image.getHeight();
    width = image.getWidth();
    // allocates another BufferedImage object whose size is
    // the same as the one of the wanted icon
    BufferedImage part = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    switch(i){
    case 1:
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        x = width*(1/3);
        y = 0;
        break;
    case 3:
        x = width*(2/3);
        y = 0;
        break;
    case 4:
        x = 0;
        y = height*(1/3);
        break;
    case 5:
        x=width*(1/3);
        y=height*(1/3);
        break;
    case 6:
        x=width*(2/3);
        y=height*(1/3);
        break;
    case 7:
        x = 0;
        y=height*(2/3);
        break;
    case 8:
        x = width*(1/3);
        y = height*(2/3);
        break;
    }

    //Intializes leftTopX and leftTopY for each button after switch
    leftTopX = width*(1/3)+x;
    leftTopY = height*(1/3)+y;

    // copies the data from "image" to "part"
    System.out.println(x + " xy " + y);
    System.out.println(leftTopY + " leftxy " + leftTopX);
    for(;x<width;x++){
        for(;y<height;y++){
            part.setRGB(x,y, image.getRGB(x+leftTopX, y+leftTopY));
        }
    }

    // creates an icon whose content is already in "part"
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon();
    icon.setImage(part);

    // returns to the caller
    return icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing a integer division...

```
x = width*(1/3);
y = 0;
```

`1/3` is equal to `0`

You should try using either a `float` or `double` as the divisor...

```
x = width*(1/3f);
```

or

```
x = (int)(width*(1/3.0));
```

for example...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing break in your switch cases.

Also remember to add a tag, for the language you are using to your posts.

Comment: Alright I added the break statements but I am still getting 0 and 0 for x and y

Comment: How do you call this method. (And also: How about renaming i, or even better: make it an enum instead :} - btw: Have you tried to print width and height. Sounds like they are 0.

Comment: I have printed them at every point and they are fine I commented out the switch statement and have isolated the issue to that but I don't know why. I call the method  like this: Icon icon1 = extractIcon(path,1);